# Halving a user input number. I can double. Just not Halve

Tags: c#, user-input

I am looking to halve a number that is input by the user through a GUI. For example, The user types in the number 10, it should say 5. I know how to double the value, but I am having troubles halving it.

Comment: What sort of troubles? Can you please clarify your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just divide by two:

```
var half = userNumber / 2;
```

Comment: As he can multiply, perhaps `var half = userNumber * 0.5` would be better?

Comment: That would actually work better because multiplying by .5 will cast the result to a floating point number. Dividing by two will truncate the decimal point.

Comment: @christophano: Great catch! First I wondered how a programmer could post this question, then I noticed three(3) downvoters claiming the question to be _unclear what you are asking_. Is this _Planet X_?

Comment: @Gene: Good point, though `float f = 7 / 2f;` will also return 3.5.